# Grab output from container in Docker SDK

Tags: docker, go, sdk

I'm trying to run a container using Docker SDK for golang and I can't get the output from the container. I'm using the following code for that that actually runs the container, but doesn't sends back stderr and stdout of the application. Can you advice what I'm doing wrong?

```
type dckr struct {
    cli      *client.Client
    username string
    password string
    addr     string
    ctx      context.Context
}

func (d *dckr) Run(containername string, image string, command []string, bind []string, stdout io.Writer, stderr io.Writer) error {
    log.Printf("[Create] %s -> %s \n", image, containername)

    res, err := d.cli.ContainerCreate(
        d.ctx,
        &container.Config{
            User:         "root",
            AttachStdout: true,
            AttachStderr: true,
            Image:        image,
            Cmd:          command,
        },
        &container.HostConfig{
            AutoRemove: true,
            Binds:      bind,
        },
        &network.NetworkingConfig{},
        containername,
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("[Create] Failed. %s", err)
        return err
    }
    defer d.cli.ContainerRemove(d.ctx, res.ID, types.ContainerRemoveOptions{Force: true})

    log.Printf("[Create] id: %s \n", res.ID)
    for wrn := range res.Warnings {
        log.Printf("[Create] %s \n", wrn)
    }

    rsp, err := d.cli.ContainerAttach(d.ctx, containername, types.ContainerAttachOptions{
        Stream: false,
        Stdout: true,
        Stderr: true,
        Logs:   true,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("[Attach] Fail. %s \n", err)
        return err
    }
    log.Printf("[Attach] %s", res.ID)
    defer rsp.Close()

    err = d.cli.ContainerStart(d.ctx, res.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("[Run] Fail. %s \n", err)
        return err
    }

    _, err = stdcopy.StdCopy(stdout, stderr, rsp.Reader)
    return err
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error or what happens?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Just an empty output. I tried to run simple tools like `ls /` or `find /` but I got nothing..

Comment: Shouldn't the Start happen before Attach? And you should attached to the `res.ID` and not `containername`? Btw you should change `containername` to `imagename` to make sure core is more readable with docker terms

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks for the suggestion! Actually it turned out that if I pass `Stream: true` then it works like a charm. I've no idea why it's so. As for Start/Attach order - there is a time lag between container start and attachment to it, so I don't want to miss any data from the container output.

Comment: Go SDK doesn't have that well documented. But if you look at the Python documentation `stream (bool) – Return container output progressively as an iterator of strings, rather than a single string.`

Comment: @CaptainRR could you guide me please about what do I need to do to accomplish what you are trying to achieve? I mean don't understand: where is the code to be dockerized? how do you config the machine type to run the container?, why aren't you assining an timeout to execute the container? how do you restrict memory an cpu usage from the code? Thank you :D

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias I just didn't requiere that. My task was just to run a container to use isolation features of docker without imposing any limits on resources. Frankly speaking, it was just for a CTF task :)

Comment: @CaptainRR after ContainerExecCreate try attaching ContainerExecAttach which provides Reader for the attached the "execId", which you can use it to get the output. https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client#Client.ContainerExecAttach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was asked in 2017 and I'm answering it in 2022. I understand the APIs might have changed, but I have landed on a similar boat.

Let's not talk about how to start a container as you seem to have already done that. Here is my code to fetch the logs from a given container:

```golang
// GetLogs return logs from the container io.ReadCloser. It's the caller duty
// duty to do a stdcopy.StdCopy. Any other method might render unknown
// unicode character as log output has both stdout and stderr. That starting
// has info if that line is stderr or stdout.
func GetLogs(ctx context.Context, cli *client.Client, contName string) (logOutput io.ReadCloser) {
    options := types.ContainerLogsOptions{ShowStdout: true}

    out, err := cli.ContainerLogs(ctx, contName, options)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return out
}
```

You can call this GetLogs from another routine. I am saving both of the stream in specific files. But you may want to use `os.Stdout` and `os.Stderr` if you just want to see them on your terminal:

```golang
func main() {
    stdoutLog, _ := os.Create("yourContainerName.log")
    defer stdoutLog.Close()
    stderrLog, _ := os.Create("yourContainerName.err")
    defer stderrLog.Close()

    var stdout bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    
    containerLog := docker.GetLogs(ctx, dc, "yourContainerName")
    stdcopy.StdCopy(&stdout, &stderr, containerLog)
    stdoutLog.Write(stdout.Bytes())
    stderrLog.Write(stderr.Bytes())
}
```

Let me know the second part if you still have confusion. I'm happy to help as I had a similar problem.

Comment: Exactly one year later I found that this is still the correct way.